# JAXB \ Annox \ Package \ ObjectFactory

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annox

I have some problems when using Annox + JAXB with ObjectFactory class.

For example, we have 2 packages with bean classes:

1. com.my.example.entity.beans.pack1:
   a) Bean1
   b) Bean2
   c) Bean3
2. com.my.example.entity.beans.pact2:
   a) Bean4
   b) Bean5

I have common package for common classes:
com.my.example.entity.common
ObjectFactory is in this package. It should contain methods for creating objects for *.beans.pack1 and *beans.pack2.

For bean fields mapping i use *.ann.xml files (for example: Bean1.ann.xml)

How i must to correctly create ObjectFactory and JAXB instance for this task?